# How do I constrain my python script to only accepting one argument? (argparse)

Tags: python, argparse

I would like a script that has (for example) three arguments:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--a",help="Argument a")
parser.add_argument("--b",help="Argument b")
parser.add_argument("--c",help="Argument c")
args= parser.parse_args()
```

But make it so that it is only possible to specify only either 'a','b', or 'c' at any give time e.g. you can specify 'a' but not 'b' or 'c' Is this possible and how would I achieve it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`argparse` lets you specify this by using the [`add_mutually_exclusive_group()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) method.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g.add_argument("--a",help="Argument a")
g.add_argument("--b",help="Argument b")
g.add_argument("--c",help="Argument c")
args= parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` mentioned above to check this on the `argparse` level already.

If you like to have more control about error message and the like, you can of course check the results later:

```
if len([x for x in args.a, args.b, args.c if x is not None]) > 1:
  raise Exception("Not allowed!")
```

Comment: That will fail if one of the arguments uses action="store_true" et c though. Not what the question asks about, but useful to keep in mind.